# Ugly, broken table in pdf generated by sphinx latexpdf from rst

Tags: csv, python-sphinx, restructuredtext, pdflatex

need some help with sphinx latexpdf output.
Have an document version csv-table in rst file. In html looks perfect, in pdf terrible.
my table:

```
.. csv-table:: 
:header: Version, Date, Description
:widths: 15, 20, 50

34343, 02/04/2015, "| Added *httsdfsdps* support"
3434, 14/11/2014, "| Added *folsdfsdlow* parameter to *hgfhfg*"
34343, 13/05/2014, "| Added *fdsf* parameter to *dfgdfgdfgdfgfdgdfgdfgdf*"
21321, 29/10/2013, "| Added *sdfsdf* parameter to *dfgsgfds*           
| Deprecated afsfsdf interface"
312321, 05/03/2013, "| Added *dsfsdfsddsfsd* parameter to *dfgdfgdfgdfgdfgdf*             
| Documented *dfgdgd*"
213211, 28/02/2013, "Added *!=* operator in *fghfghfg*"
2132132, 26/02/2013, "Added *dsfsdfsdfsdfsdfsd* in *fghf*"
213219, 07/02/2013, "| Added *jsonhash* event format
| Added *filter* parameter in event connection
| Added *group* and *map* parameter to *nph-muu-sf*"
21321321, 30/01/2013, "| Added *height* parameter in *dfgdfgdfdfg*
| Added *dfgdfgdfgdf* in dfgdfgdfgdf"
```

HTML
[image: 1]

PDF
[image: 2]

Table is not full in pdf. And this style with spaces at top, bottom near text in cells. Why latex does not take size from rst? 
Can i make it better? How? 
Thanks for help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know your question has been posted for a while, but in case it is still an issue, and for posterity who may come upon this here is how I fixed this issue in an rst doc of my own. I had the same issue, but using a standard rst table drawn out explicitly like so.

```
+--------+--------+---------+
|Column 1|Column 2| Column 3|
+========+========+=========+
|Value   |Value   |Value    |
+--------+--------+---------+
```

And so on with many cells that would show the same behavior of running over the page end. The solution was using the class: longtable argument, and then very carefully indenting the table so that the class was applied. Like so:

```
.. table:: Table Title
  :class: longtable
  +--------+--------+---------+
  |Column 1|Column 2| Column 3|
  +========+========+=========+
  |Value   |Value   |Value    |
  +--------+--------+---------+
```

This when rendered in pdf would properly break the table over multiple pages. You should be able to use the same class on a csv table.

Answer (score 2):

The list-table directory works. Just include the longtable class.

Example:

```
.. list-table:: Table Name
   :widths: 5 30
   :header-rows: 1
   :align: center
   :class: longtable

   * - **Column1**
     - **Column 2**

   * - Row1itemsforcolumn1
     - Row1itemsforcolumn2
.
.
.very very long table
.
.
   * - Row1itemsforcolumnn
     - Row1itemsforcolumnn
```

This gives a clean-looking PDF output whereby the contents are continued on the next page.

[Final Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGNnb.png)

Answer (score 1):

that is my solution:
this issue in my .rst document is because my table is not too long. if your table is much longer, it will switch to next pages automatically. i have 20 rows in my table. so i change one row:

```
+-----------+-----------+  
|           |           |  
|           |           |  
|           |           |  
+-----------+-----------+  

to   
+-----------+-----------+  
|           |           |  
+           +           +  
|           |           |  
+-----------+-----------+
```

it will not change your table style in pdf, but actually the table become 21 rows. when my table has 30 rows. it switch to next pages automatically.  but this way may be a little stupid...